# Validating time and date in javascript for html form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I've tried many ways to validate the date and time with Javascript functions but none seem to work. I'd like to alert users when their date input is of a past date whereas the time start cannot be the same as time end and it cannot be later than time end. 
My HTML codes:

```
<p>
<label> Date:
 <input type="date" id="date" name="date" required />
</label>
</p>

<p>
<label> Time start:
 <input type="time" id="timeStart" name="timeStart" required />
</label>
</p>

<p>
<label> Time end:
 <input type="time" id="timeEnd" name="timeEnd" required />
</label>
</p>
```

Javascript I tried:

```
 function valiDate(date) {
     var today=new Date();
     var inputDate=document.getElementById("date").value;

     if (inputDate < today) {
         alert("Your event cannot happen in the past.");
     }
   }



 function checkDate(date)
   {

    var dateInput=document.getElementById("date").value;
    var parts=date.split("/");
    var yearInput=parts[0];
    var monthInput=parts[2];
    var dayInput=parts[3];


    var minYear = 1902;
    var maxYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();
    var maxMonth = (new Date()).getMonth();
    var currentDay = (new Date()).getDate();

    if (yearInput<maxYear || monthInput<maxMonth || dayInput<currentDay ) {
        alert("Event cannot be held in the past. Move on.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the JavaScript you say that you tried please.

Comment: Also post any errors that were in console with the js that you tried. Or maybe summarize what you tried and what about those methods didn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The method used for comparison of dates is wrong.

```
d1.getTime() === d2.getTime();
d1.getTime() !== d2.getTime();
```

Use getTime() operator or dates.compare() function.
If you want to split the dates, the use '-' to split them.

Here is a working jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/BoyWithSilverWings/rc08otjc/

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
     function validDate() {     
     var today=new Date();
     var inputDate = new Date(document.getElementById("date").value);
     today.setHours(0,0,0,0);    
     if (inputDate < today) {
         alert("Your event cannot happen in the past.");        
     } 
     else {
        var startTime =  TimeinMillisec(document.getElementById("timeStart").value);  
         var endTime =  TimeinMillisec(document.getElementById("timeEnd").value);

         if( startTime > endTime)
          alert("Event cannot be held");
          else
          alert("Done");

     }
   }



  function TimeinMillisec(gTime)
   {
     var parts=gTime.split(" ");
     var hhmm = parts[0].split(":");
       hhmm[0] = parseInt(hhmm[0]);
     if( parts[1].toLowerCase() === "pm")
        hhmm[0] = parseInt(hhmm[0]+12);
        var seconds = parseInt( ((+hhmm[0]) * 60 * 60) + ((+hhmm[1]) * 60));     
     return seconds;
   }
```